# Step-down converter? Who can recognize this IC?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, identification

[image]

This IC is marked "SCD". Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: As it is ther is very little information to go on, hence making it hard to answer your question. Can you create/find a schematic for this circuit? Also a zoomed out photo would be helpful also.

Answer (score 4):

It’s a 3MHz 2A Step Down Converter, a Chinese version of the TI TLV62065TDSGRQ1

[image: photo of ICs]

Image source: [Aliexpress - Origin-chips store](https://m.nl.aliexpress.com/item/1005002803850056.html?spm=a2g0n.productlist.0.0.2c70XzqhXzqh2W&browser_id=7f5466aa7cac4ee2ae2b19388e239513&aff_trace_key=22722359fa1a4e66980e363cd53fa24f-1647445411366-09391-UneMJZVf&aff_platform=msite&m_page_id=jxtgg5kzaqqcazga182207f49f2c54d3d831e5f400&gclid=&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21EUR%21%217.29%21%21%212.56%21%21%402100bdec16584025894162127e20f9%2112000022262491971%21sea&algo_pvid=8bf1bc72-cb1b-4537-85e3-be0cff9eb739)